# Computing Elliptic Curves of Conductor Divisible by a Large Prime Factor

Tags: elliptic-curves, nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

A little while ago, I came across a paper (or slides from a talk or something) that seemed to suggest that the modular symbol method for computing elliptic curves over $\mathbf{Q}$ of prescribed conductor $N$ works better when $N$ lacks large prime factors.

I'm trying to find the reference again, but I'm having a really hard time.  I have a feeling that it had some connection to John Cremona's program, but this could be wrong.

Could someone please point me in the direction of such a reference?

Did I imagine this paper/presentation?  That is to say, is it even true that the modular symbol method is less efficient when $N$ has a large prime factor?

Thanks!

Comment: I thought the other way around. The case of prime $N$ is best, see Mestre's method of graphs. And each prime divisor gives an Atkin-Lehner involution for more linear algebra, and more oldforms. But I do not know for sure.

Comment: Agreed. I'm pretty sure that the case of highly composite N is the *worst* case, based on what I've heard from John about how he does his computations.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps what I (think I) read was specific to the situation where N has a few small prime factors raised to large powers and a few large prime factors.